# javascript ajax on submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

i am using a google map api to get location. i have used the below function onchange of address field. it is working properly onchange. i have used same function on submit in the same form to checking the function once again while submitting using a onsubmit attribute. but while submitting i cant able to get answer from this ajax because of the that return by using this return true the form submit with pout getting answer.

please any one find a solution for this

```
function validatePlaceForm(){

            var frm = document.frmOncampus;     

            var oncampusAddress = frm.oncampusAddress.value;

            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            //document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML=''
            var result =xmlhttp.responseText;
                //alert(result);
                var both  =result.split("|");
                    frm.oncampusLatitude.value=both[0];
                    frm.oncampusLongtitude.value=both[1];
            }
          }
            var url='latlog.php?address='+oncampusAddress;

            xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlhttp.send();

            return true;

        }
```

Comment: You should return true only when the address is valid otherwise return false. Please include your html code for more detail.

Comment: Maybe it is time to look into [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)?

Comment: i tried in jquery also both are getting same problem.

Comment: in my html code their is nothing big it will just echo a value. my html is okay the problem is only with onsubmit call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this will never work because the way you're using the XHR there is asynchronous:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true); // true means asynchronous
```

As the call is asynchronous the result of the function will have no result on the running of the Ajax request.

If you want to continue with using this function just change this last parameter to `false`, i.e.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false); // will now be synchronous
```

You also won't need a `onreadystatechange` handler now. Bear in mind that this will obviously make the XHR call synchronous on your `onchange` event too; maybe customise the function to accept a flag for `is_synchronous` or something.

You might also want to consider adding a timestamp onto your requests so that the browser does not cache the response.

Answer (score 0):

Change the return value from true to false and call this function like this: 
`onsubmit="return validatePlaceForm();"`

This should do the trick.

Comment: i have already tried that too if i use the return false and onsubmit="return validatePlaceForm();" the ajax process is done but the form is not submitted

Answer (score 0):

Check for the response coming from AJAX. If response is blank then return false, otherwise return true.